# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException (Chess Programming)

Tags: java

Can anyone please help me figure why this is happening??? The exception happens when I click on a button on the board. Each square on the board is painted with JButton.

I got a `java.lang.NullPointerException` pointing to these code lines :

> **BoardState.moveFrom_To(BoardState.java:84)** - boardState[start.getRow()][start.getCol()].moveTo(end);
>
> **movePiece(CommandExecutions.java:257)** - board.moveFrom_To(selectedPiece, loc);
>
> **processOne(CommandExecutions.java:331)** - movePiece(loc);
>
> **MainFrame.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:263)** - loc = processLocation(new Location(y,x));

Here is the exception message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ja264chess.chess.board.BoardState.moveFrom_To(BoardState.java:84)
    at com.ja264chess.chess.menus.CommandExecutions.movePiece(CommandExecutions.java:257)
    at com.ja264chess.chess.menus.CommandExecutions.processOne(CommandExecutions.java:331)
    at com.ja264chess.chess.menus.MainFrame.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:263)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

ChessPiece

```
public abstract void moveTo(Location moveLoc);
```

King, Queen, Knight, etc...

```
public void moveTo(Location moveLoc)
    {
        setLocation(moveLoc);
    }
```

The method

```
public void processOne(Location loc)
    {
        if(board.getState()[loc.getRow()][loc.getCol()]!=null)
        {
            if((board.getState()[loc.getRow()][loc.getCol()].getColor() && isWhiteTurn) || (!board.getState()[loc.getRow()][loc.getCol()].getColor() && !isWhiteTurn))
            {
                mainframe.enableSide(isWhiteTurn);          
                selectedPiece = loc;
                mainframe.resetBackground();
                mainframe.resetBorders();
                mainframe.selected(selectedPiece);
                System.out.println("selected Piece" +selectedPiece);
                processMoves();
            }
            else
            {
                movePiece(loc);
                board.resetOtherPawns(loc);
                checkPromotion(loc);
                checkGameOver();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            movePiece(loc);
            board.resetOtherPawns(loc);
            checkPromotion(loc);
            checkGameOver();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: So either `boardState` is `null` or `boardState[start.getRow()][start.getCol()].[start.getRow()][start.getCol()]` is `null`...

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right. When I debugged it, I found out that [start.getRow()][start.getCol()] is null. Why is that?

Comment: Debug again and see why it isn't initialised...

Comment: I think you don't understand the meaning of "runnable" example

Comment: Not sure if I do. Should I upload the whole program?

Comment: Runnable means we can can copy and paste it into an IDE and just run it without writing additional code ourselves... (and ideally the program is just so small that it demonstrates the problem)

Comment: There are too many classes in the program which makes copy paste impossible. Can I copy paste the classes throwing the exception?

Comment: Hi ManOnAMission. Debug on eclipse isn't showing why it isn't initialized.

Comment: Please post the code to your BoardState class. We need to see code to figure out what is wrong with it!

Comment: Thanks Eric. I posted it now.

Comment: Please verify that the board initialises correctly. Also check that the ChessPiece retrieved on the move_to method is not null. What happens if the input location is not valid? I see a lack of constraints and contracts which are not specified but that, ideally, should be. Also, from a design perspective, I would consider using a Table as provided by Guava, a double-index data structure, rather than a two dimensional array. Also, consider posting the move(Location) function of Chesspiece. Your logic for moving pieces seems out of order.

Comment: From the provided code, either start is null or the object in your array as indexed by the values of start is null. I would suggest running your debugger to check which is the case!

Comment: Thanks Eric I posted the method as requested for ChessPiece. The board initializes correctly. The thing is that when I click a piece, I notice that "start" parameter of moveFromTo method is null whereby "end" parameter is set to the piece location. But start is suppose to be set with the piece location.

Comment: Well that is your culprit then as calling a method on a null reference will result in the Exception you got. May I suggest using an IDE where you can specify contracts and use annotations to define contracts? Check http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis for example!

Comment: Thanks for your responses Eric. I think I found what the problem really is. This line is the problem; "selectedPiece = loc". The variable "selectedpiece" won't initialize with the method's parameter "loc". Do you know why a field variable won't initialized with a method's parameter? I posted the method above. Thanks alot everyone.

Comment: Just wanted to add that "loc" isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

As determined in the comments, the issue was passing of a `null` reference where none was expected. Unfortunately, these issues creep up quite often. One way to remedy these situations is the use of tools from [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Specify contracts that need to be upheld by your objects. In Java, especially when using Eclipse, this can be done by automated [Null Analysis](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis).

Using this strategy, passing of a possible `null` reference could have been caught early. Additionally, with the IDE issuing warnings and errors on dubious code, the overall quality of the code design can be improved. It is definitely worth checking out!

Comment: By the way I did checked "wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis". I think it's outdated. The installation link seemed to be broken when I tried installing the plugin on eclipse. I'll look more into Null Analysis later. Thanks Eric

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eric and everyone that contributed to my question. Eventually, I was able to fix it. The field "selectedPiece" was null, so I had to created "setter" and "getter" property methods to initialize it properly. And that solved it for me.